# Error: Undefined Method for the Type <Interface>

Tags: java, interface

I am implementing a Multi-agent simulation using Repast Symphony. I got the following error which I believe has nothing to do with Repast platform. so here it goes:

I have an Interface:

```
public interface Located {
  public int getX();
  public int getY();
}
```

I have two other classes that implement it:

```
public class Carrier implements Located{
  public int getX(){..}
  public int getY(){..} }

public class Gold implements Located{
  public int getX(){..}
  public int getY(){..} }
```

Also I have a class LocateAdder which implements another built-in interface:

```
public class LocateAdder<Located> implements GridAdder<Located> {


@Override
public void add(Grid<Located> destination, Located object) 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
destination.moveTo(object, object.getX(), object.getY());

}
                                                                 }
```

I cant even compile the code.  I get red line under getX and getY which says "The method getX() is undefined for the type Located".  I am not sure why this is happening as obviously the interface has the signature of the two methods. Any one can spot what is going on?  Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
public class LocateAdder<Located> implements GridAdder<Located> {
```

to

```
public class LocateAdder implements GridAdder<Located> {
```

In the first sample, you're declaring a new type variable named `Located` which shadows the type called `Located`.

Comment: This solved this error but I got an error somewhere else in my code.  I use an object of the class LocateAdder as a parameter in another class constructor, and there I need to parametrize it with the type, so <Located> has the be there I guess.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Fonah If `LocateAdder` needs to be generic, declare a type parameter with a different name so as not to shadow the name `Located`.

Comment: Let me explain a little bit what I am trying to accomplish.  In Repast when I define a grid, where the agents live, I need to determine the adder which is a class that define where the agents are added in the grid(i.e. the location). There is only Random built-in adder which adds the agents to a random locations in the grid.  In my model I need to add the agents to a predetermined locations in the grid hence I thought I can implement my adder.  So to do that I created the Interface Located and made my two agents Carrier and Gold implement it. Then I created the adder class which should ..TBC

Comment: Then I created the adder class which should work for both agents so I made it generic by parameterizing it over the interface Located. Thus the class LocateAdder has to be generic over the type Locate.  So that's why I think your suggestion wont work in my case.  Not sure if there is another way to do the same thing. Any other suggestion? thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @Fonah I won't comment on design. You might get better help at Programmers or Codereview sites (part of the stack exchange network). The point is to understand what the two lines of code above are doing. If `LocateAdder` is a `GridAdder` with type `Located`, then the correct way to model that is with the second option. The first option has no notion of `Located`. It is equivalent to `public class LocateAdder<T> implements GridAdder<T>`.